# Unity 3D Sandbox Game Problems

Tags: c#, sandbox, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to add the ability to place different blocks (prefabs) in the world and I just keep getting errors and I am struggling. Here is the code for the inventory:

```
public bool displayInventory;

public Behaviour PlayerController;

public int currentPrefabId;

public GameObject playerInv;

public Transform playerTransform;

public Vector3 playerPosition;

void Start () {
    displayInventory = false;
    playerPosition = playerTransform.position;
}

void FixedUpdate() {

    playerPosition = playerTransform.position;

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Open Inventory"))
    {
        displayInventory = true;

    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Cancel"))
    {
        displayInventory = false;
    }

    if (displayInventory == true)
    {
        showInventory(playerInv);
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        Cursor.visible = true;
    }

    if (displayInventory == false)
    {
        closeInventory(playerInv);
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
    {
        Sign.placePrefabSign();
    }

    if (Input.GetButton("Fire2"))
    {
        Wood.placePrefabWood();
    }
}

public static void showInventory(GameObject playerInv)
{
    playerInv.SetActive(true);  
}

public static void closeInventory(GameObject playerInv)
{
    playerInv.SetActive(false);
}

public static void PlacePrefab(int currentPrefabId, GameObject[] Prefabs, Vector3 playerPosition)
{
    Instantiate(Prefabs[currentPrefabId], playerPosition, new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?  (Parts are still of an older system I tried out).

I am getting these errors:

[image]

I've uploaded the source code it is here:

[Source Code Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4pfqhwcg5935sjy/Project%20Sandbox.zip?dl=0)

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Edit this post with errors your getting.

Comment: @TimeHopper You are obviously trying to access and use a null object which causes a `NullReferenceException`. Debug line by line to detect that object.

Comment: See at woods.cs at line 14 ... what is the object with null reference ? Check if you have initialized all the variables/objects!

Comment: @SimonePessotto It is the prefab for a test block called wood! If you want the source code for the entire project it is here [Source Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4pfqhwcg5935sjy/Project%20Sandbox.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Make sure you have filled the references in the inspector for the script. You can drag and drop the desired gameobject there if you don't want to do it by code. I suggest learning the basics first and try to figure out the errors yourself... They do tell you what is wrong and where it went wrong...

Comment: @Savlon I have learnt the basics but I'm still new unity and I've released the source code as said before and everything is filled in the editor!

Comment: @TimeHopper Savlon is right .. check the references! It must be some not-filled reference. Now I'll try to check the source code ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Now I understood what you wanted to do. You don't need a Wood.cs script to instantiate a prefab on button pressed. So change your code of `inventory.cs` like:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class inventory : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool displayInventory;

    public Behaviour PlayerController;

    public int currentPrefabId;

    public GameObject playerInv;

    public Transform playerTransform;

    public Vector3 playerPosition;

    public GameObject m_oPlayer // <- NEW! : Must be linked in the editor with the player (RigidBodyFPSController);

    public GameObject m_oWoodPrefab; // <- NEW! :Must be linked in the editor with the prefab

    void Start () {
        displayInventory = false;
        playerPosition = playerTransform.position;
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {

        playerPosition = playerTransform.position;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Open Inventory"))
        {
            displayInventory = true;

        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Cancel"))
        {
            displayInventory = false;
        }

        if (displayInventory == true)
        {
            showInventory(playerInv);
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }

        if (displayInventory == false)
        {
            closeInventory(playerInv);
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            Sign.placePrefabSign();
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2")) // <- CHANGED
        {
            Instantiate(m_oWoodPrefab, playerPosition, m_oPlayer.transform.rotation);
        }
    }

    public static void showInventory(GameObject playerInv)
    {
        playerInv.SetActive(true);  
    }

    public static void closeInventory(GameObject playerInv)
    {
        playerInv.SetActive(false);
    }

    public static void PlacePrefab(int currentPrefabId, GameObject[] Prefabs, Vector3 playerPosition)
    {
        Instantiate(Prefabs[currentPrefabId], playerPosition, new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }

}
```

You can delete the `wood.cs` script you don't need it. And check your code because you have to avoid the "new" keyword to create MonoBehavior objects, also static functions. I didn't change the sign function also, but you should ...

**Original Answer:**

Ok, I checked the source code.

You're using the constructors for the scripts class as "Initialization" of the associate gameobject. This is not the right way.

The errors comes because the reference of the gameobject was not available at constructor time. So null was returned and the `Instantiate` functions crashed.

The are standard functions that Unity3D provides, for example

```
void Start ()
```

> Start is called on the frame when a script is enabled just before any
>   of the Update methods is called the first time.
>
> Like the Awake function, Start is called exactly once in the lifetime
>   of the script. However, Awake is called when the script object is
>   initialised, regardless of whether or not the script is enabled. Start
>   may not be called on the same frame as Awake if the script is not
>   enabled at initialisation time.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html

Also, there are several other problems with your code ... I suggest you to watch some of unity tutorial.

So, this is code from the wood.cs scripts that works (I just tried it):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Wood : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject prefab;

    public Transform playerTransfom;

    public Quaternion rotation;

    void Start() {
        Instantiate(prefab, playerTransfom.position, rotation);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am 90% sure you should not be calling `new Wood()`.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain Ok what should i be calling then?

Comment: @Simon Pessotto So do you mean that that code works? So I should use that if so thanks! Also I already looked for a tutorial but there aren't any available for making a 3D Sandbox Game!

Comment: @Time Hopper  yes that code works (i tried it) and you should also remove the placePrefabWood() function as scott chamberlain told us.

Comment: @scott chamberlain yes, of course. I forget to check all the code. That static function should be removed. (I'll will edit the answer)

Comment: @TimeHopper please check the updates, now I understood what you want. If it fix your problem please vote +1 and set the answer as the right answer.

Comment: @SimonePessotto Ok Thanks